# Python: Extracting text from a image

Tags: python, computer-vision, python-tesseract

I want to extract (91)4608 from the below image. I have several of the images, the pattern I'm looking for is (91)xxxx, x is a digit. I tried using pytesseract as below

```
from PIL import Image
import pytesseract, re
f = "1591107148_festo.jpg"
t = pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.open(f))
print(t)
```

But I get a garbage output as below, I believe it's encoded and I notice that all the text is not extracted.

```
sanna vioxva ON ‘sivan Hs3ae4 NOSAL -Aa aanesia

0 yep OF 10d
‘enous @989id

Bq ayesphyoque 9 (639,
ee anes 8
Siz aon
ish Be peapoyemes | oP
a RLM

eLY

pap Buinieg| §
Bz) Zoy aig Suns!
s$y084 U0} ayn
```

could you please help me out, thanks.

Image used in the above is..

Answer (score 1):

`pytesseract` is designed for documents, and expects the text to be straight on the page (like a normal document). If you flip your image, it should work a lot better.

EDIT:
with code:

```
from PIL import Image
import pytesseract, re
f = "1591107148_festo.jpg"
t = pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.open(f).rotate(270))
print(t)
```

I get:

```
ju have questions
ase call ou ones

Mam ount Per Serving:

~ {Calories 180 Calories from fat £70
AT AND/OR POULTRY, Sf

BACTERIA THAT COULD CAUSE IL

WISHANDLED OR COOKED INP
PROTECTION, FOLLOW THESE SAFE

VEEP REFRIGERATED
THAW IN REPRIGERA

Se _
=

‘otal Cal
rotein
fe

Please vomere of DP
prior to defrosting

DISTRIBUTED BY: TYSON FRESH MEATS, INC DAKOTA DUNES
```

I think if you preprocess the image, i.e. converting to a binary image, and tilt it until the text is exactly straight, you will get even better results.

Comment: could you tell me a way to decode the text to english?